# Files and folders showing red after moving to a different folder in Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode10

I moved multiple files and sub-folders to different folders. It made project tree structure logical and understandable. Now several folders and files are showing red.

To fix this I tried to move a few red folders to another location, it triggered Xcode Indexing which turned a few files to black again(fixed).

I assume it is a bug with Xcode. Because when I moved red folders here-&-there few issues fixed automatically.

[image]

If I checkout to older commit I'll **lose 7 days work**.

`Path change solution` cannot work since I've 100s of files which are grouped into 80+ different folders.

Comment: What I would do is just remove the problematic files from the Project Navigator and then import them again.

Comment: @there are 100s of files grouped into 80+ folder and in nested structure. In addition those files are scattered into actual Mac folder here-n-there. Plus there are those files mixed which are not showing red into project tree.

Comment: • In Xcode select a red file. • Press ⌥⌘1 (Identity and Type Inspector) • Click on the tiny folder icon below the *Location* popup. • Navigate to the new location and choose the corresponding file.

Comment: @vadian Please read the last line of the question or last commit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with `Xcode 10.1` when I moved a bunch of files to a different folder. When I unchecked/rechecked the `Target Membership` in the `File Inspector` ( ⌥⌘1) for each file, it went away.